# what schema should I use for my tsconfig.json file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, jsonschema, tsconfig

[image]

What schema should I use for my tsconfig.json file? I'm not sure why - but suddenly visual studio keeps inviting me to select a schema for my tsconfig.json file. I have never noticed this before. When I edit the file, just above line 1 I see <No Schema Selected>. If I click it I get a list of about a zillion schemas. I haven't got the faintest idea which one to use. Any recommendations?

Provisionally I have randomly picked https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to figure out why I lost intellisense while editing the tsconfig. I found the following in the list and it seems to be working well.

https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig.json

Comment: That looks much more sensible. Thanks!